# Finding closed-form maximum of a function with no obvious root

Tags: optimization, roots, maxima-minima, closed-form

I have the below function:

$$\pi(x) = \frac{s_0\cdot \left(1-\left(\frac{s_1}{s_1+x \cdot \lambda}\right)^{k}\right) \cdot r_1}{s_0\cdot \left(1-\left(\frac{s_1}{s_1+x \cdot \lambda}\right)^{k}\right) \cdot \gamma+ r_0}- x$$
with:

- $x, s_0, s_1, r_0, r_1 \in R^+$
- $\lambda, \gamma \in [0,1]$
- $k \in \{0.25, 4\}$

I am trying to find the $x$ that maximises $\pi(x)$ for both k values (by graphing the function on Desmos, one can see there exists a maximum).

I have tried to solve $\frac{d\pi(x)}{dx}=0$ but there is no root afaik.

What else should I try? How to find the maximum with a closed form formula?

EDIT: adding my reasoning on finding the root by solving $\frac{d\pi(x)}{dx}=0$, notations inspired from comments.

We solve $\frac{d \pi(x)}{dx} = 0$
i.e.
$$ \frac{\left(s_{0}\cdot r_{1}\cdot r_{0}\cdot\lambda\cdot k\cdot\left(\frac{s_{1}}{s_{1}+\lambda\cdot x}\right)^{1+k}\right)}{s_{1}\cdot\left(s_{0}\cdot\gamma\cdot\left(\left(\frac{s_{1}}{s_{1}+\lambda\cdot x}\right)^{k}-1\right)-r_{0}\right)^{2}}-1=0$$

$$\left(s_{0}\cdot r_{1}\cdot r_{0}\cdot\lambda\cdot k\cdot\left(\frac{s_{1}}{s_{1}+\lambda\cdot x}\right)^{1+k}\right) = s_{1}\cdot\left(s_{0}\cdot\gamma\cdot\left(\left(\frac{s_{1}}{s_{1}+\lambda\cdot x}\right)^{k}-1\right)-r_{0}\right)^{2}$$

We introduce:

- $a=s_{0}\cdot r_{1}\cdot r_{0}\cdot\lambda \cdot k$
- $y=s_1+\lambda \cdot x$

and rewrite
$$
\pm\sqrt{a} \cdot s_1^{\frac{k}{2}} \cdot y^{-\frac{k+1}{2}} = s_0 \cdot \gamma \cdot \left(\left(\frac{s_{1}}{y}\right)^{k}-1\right)-r_{0}
$$
$$
\pm \sqrt{a} \cdot s_1^{\frac{k}{2}} \cdot y^{-\frac{k+1}{2}} - s_0 \cdot \gamma \cdot s_{1}^k \cdot y^{-k} + s_0 \cdot \gamma +r_{0} =0
$$

and going one step further:

$$A \cdot  y^{-\frac{k+1}{2}} + B \cdot y^{-k} + C= 0$$
with:

- $A=\pm \sqrt{s_{0} \cdot r_{1} \cdot r_{0} \cdot \lambda \cdot k \cdot s_1^k}$
- $B = - s_0 \cdot \gamma \cdot s_{1}^k$
- $C=s_0 \cdot \gamma +r_{0}$

We still have $k \in \{0.25, 4\}$ which for me makes it difficult to  solve.

Note: One comment states this could be solved as a general trinomial via series expansion, which I do not yet master, what is the approach to get there?

Comment: You know, you could find a much simpler form for this function if you were willing to combine constants. In particular, let $A = \frac{\gamma}{r_1}, B = \frac{r_0}{s_0r_1}, C = \frac{\lambda}{s_1}$. This might help you figure out the error you are making in the derivative. The function is differentiable, so if it has a maximum as you claim, the derivative at that maximum is $0$. There is no other choice.

Comment: Am getting the derivatives with wolfram alpha. And then equaling it to 0 and solving there. I have also tried manually but it does not seem solvable in the domain.

Comment: Pasting in your MathJax, you find $f’(x)=0$ does correspond to the extrema on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xh41xpajge). Also the equation giving the extrema should be $\pm\sqrt a y^{-\frac{k+1}2}+\gamma s_0s_1^ky^{-k}-cs_0-r=0,y=s_1+\lambda x,a=k\lambda r_0 r_1s_1
^ks_0$ which has a closed form in terms of hypergeometric functions. See [trinomial series solution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial)

Comment: If there is a maximum or minimum in the interior of the domain (and since this function is differentiable everywhere in its domain), then the derivative will be $0$ there. It cannot have any other value. The fact that you do not find a $0$ of the derivative in the domain means either you have miscalculated the derivative, or you are wrong about it having no root in the domain, or you are wrong about the function having a maximum in its interior. So you need to figure out in which of these you are wrong. You are right about the maximum, so you either have the derivative or solving wrong.

Comment: I have expanded the derivative, and we end up with a general trinomial form, as @ТymaGaidash mentioned. I do not know how to solve that though, resources/help appreciated